# validate email cake 1.2 without a model

Tags: validation, email, cakephp

I'm trying to find a way to validate an email address using CakePHP 1.2 without a model.  Can this be done?  If so, how can I validate an email address with CakePHP 1.2 **without a model**?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use client side validation using javascript or jquery

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "validate" - it can mean many things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1] either use pure php regular expression match against (courtesy of http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}
```

2] or call the cake email validation function from:

```
$Validation =& Validation::getInstance();
$result = $Validation->email($tested_email)
```

Comment: I'd go with #2, to keep it DRY

Comment: just wondering, in what scenario does it make no sense to actually create a meaningful model and validate through it?